# Change locale in react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, localization, react-datepicker

I am using [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) NPM package,
I tried to follow documentation but I was unable to import

```
registerLocale
```

and

```
setDefaultLocale
```

from `react-datepicker`

Do you see where I make mistake?

```
 import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';



...
    <DatePicker
            { ...this.props }
            dateFormat={ this.dateFormat }
            ref={ (node) => { this.ref = node; } }
            onClickOutside={ this.clickOutside }
          />
...
```

this is code where I want to import locale.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

First of all make sure you are using the latest version of the plugin (*2.0.0*).
Then you need to also install the `date-fns` module, but for the moment the `react-datepicker` is working with the 2.0.0-alpha.23 version.

Then you need to import and register the locale you want and finally add the `locale` property to the `DatePicker`

so (*after installing the correct versions*)

```
import DatePicker, { registerLocale } from "react-datepicker";
import el from "date-fns/locale/el"; // the locale you want
registerLocale("el", el); // register it with the name you want
```

and use it

```
<DatePicker 
    locale="el"
    ...
/>
```

Working demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/7j8z7kvy06

Comment: God bless you! I couldn't find this dependency from an alpha-level external library anywhere in the react-datepicker documentation.

Comment: Any solution for non alpha version of date-fns?

Comment: Time in extended ui is not localized, need use prop timeCaption: string

Answer (score 30):

For those who don't want to depend on `date-fns` module you can define your own localization.

Here's a working demo on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/3z1kp).

```
const days = ['Pt', 'Sa', 'Ça', 'Pe', 'Cu', 'Ct', 'Pz']
const months = ['Ocak', 'Şubat', 'Mart', 'Nisan', 'Mayıs', 'Haziran', 'Temmuz', 'Ağustos', 'Eylül', 'Ekim', 'Kasım', 'Aralık']

const locale = {
  localize: {
    day: n => days[n],
    month: n => months[n]
  },
  formatLong: {
    date: () => 'mm/dd/yyyy'
  }
}

<DatePicker locale={locale} />
```

Comment: This does not work.
TypeError: formatLong.date is not a function

Comment: I've updated the answer and also put a CodeSandbox link.

Comment: This worked for me although I had to add a match property (empty callback) in locale to make it work properly.

I wanted to make appear short month via property useShortMonthInPicker alongside showMonthInPicker but I still see full month.

I looked at documentation of Locale type from date-fns but I didn't see how to do that

Comment: Sounds good - however, for reacent react-datepicker the package itselfe depends on date-fns, so I don't know how useful this is (if it actually reduces the bundle size)

Answer (score 6):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker, { registerLocale } from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import ja from "date-fns/locale/ja";

registerLocale("ja", ja);

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: new Date()
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      date
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <body>
          <DatePicker
            dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
            selected={this.state.date}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            locale='ja'
          />
        </body>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I could get the result you wanted. And I tried to make it with `moment` library but it didn't work on my code. sorry

Comment: the npm libraries I used:
* date-fns@next
* react-datepicker

Answer (score 6):

In case you want to use a locale, that is not supported by date-fns (and those are quite few), you can do a shim.

```
const monthsBG = ['Януари', 'Февруари', 'Март', 'Април', 'Май', 'Юни', 'Юли', 'Август', 'Септември', 'Октомври', 'Ноември', 'Декември'];
const daysBG = ['нед', 'пон', 'вт', 'ср', 'четв', 'пет', 'съб'];

registerLocale('bg', {
  localize: {
    month: n => monthsBG[n],
    day: n => daysBG[n]
  }, 
  formatLong:{} 
});
```

and then you can use this locale as any other

```
<DatePicker
  locale="bg"
  ...
/>
```

Comment: Thank u, dude!  Greetings from BG.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to use **registerLocale**, just use import variable name **ja** without quotes :

```
<DatePicker
  dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
  selected={this.state.date}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  locale=ja
/>
```

You can also set the default locale for all date picker fields with **setDefaultLocale** :

```
constructor (props) {
    registerLocale("ja", ja);
    setDefaultLocale("ja");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic locale imports you could use this code. However, you will get a larger package with dynamic imports:

```
constructor(props) {
    const getLocale = locale => require(`date-fns/locale/${this.props.language}/index.js`)
    this.locale = getLocale(this.props.language);
}
```

And then use

```
<DatePicker locale={this.locale} />
```