# How to get date in edit form in dd/mm/yyyy format in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, react-hooks

I am using input textfield in React with type date which stores date in format `2021-07-22T00:00:00.000Z` in MongoDB. I want the data in the edit form so that the date stored comes in edit form and we can again change it from the date picker.

The code for the input field is

```
<TextField name="purchaseDate" type="date" required variant="outlined" fullWidth value={bookData.purchaseDate} onChange={(e) => setBookData({ ...bookData, purchaseDate : e.target.value })} />
```

Comment: You haven't set the value property of the `TextField` to show the value from DB.

Comment: Seems `TextFiled`'s type is kind of `<input type='text'>`. How the date is changed for now?

Comment: TextField is like input tag in material ui so it also allows which type of input we want and here I want input of date type which on clicking shows calendar to choose date.

Comment: Does [Change locale in react-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399084/change-locale-in-react-datepicker) offer anything useful?